# R plyr summarize chunks

Tags: r, plyr

I have a table of daily temperature

```
+-------+-----+-------------+
| City  | Day | Temperature |
+-------+-----+-------------+
| Miami |   1 |          25 |
| Miami |   2 |          27 |
| Miami |   3 |          34 |
| Miami |   4 |          23 |
| Miami |   5 |          30 |
| Miami |   6 |          31 |
| Paris |   1 |          15 |
| Paris |   2 |          17 |
| Paris |   3 |          14 |
| Paris |   4 |          13 |
| Paris |   5 |          10 |
| Paris |   6 |          11 |
+-------+-----+-------------+
```

I would to be able to `summarize` them by city in chunks of `n` days.

An exemple of the result with chunks of 3 days

```
+-------+-----+---------------------+
| City  | Day |      AVGTemperature |
+-------+-----+---------------------+
| Miami | 1-3 |               28.66 |
| Miami | 4-6 |                  29 |
| Paris | 1-3 |               15.33 |
| Paris | 4-6 |                14.5 |
+-------+-----+---------------------+
```

I could do

```
AVGTemp <- ddply(temp, .(Day, City), summarize, AVGTemperature=mean(Temperature))
```

But that gives me the average for every single day. I can a make it so it returns chunks of `n` days?

Comment: You could use `cut` to create a new grouping variable.

Comment: Do you really want overlapping groups? In your example, you show Day = `1-3` and `3-6` so `3` is included in both groups. Perhaps you mean `1-3` and `4-6`?

Comment: With `dplyr` you could do: `temp %>% mutate(day2 = factor(cut(Day, 2), labels = c("1-3","4-6"))) %>% group_by(City, day2) %>% summarise(AVGTemp = mean(Temperature))`

Comment: @JasonAizkalns You are right. Edited the question

Comment: Fyi, ddply is not part of dplyr.

Comment: @Jaap is there a way I could specify the size of the chunks (ex: 3 elements per chunk)?

Comment: You could sort by and then use `rep` with the `each=3` parameter to create a grouping variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dplyr solution. Change `breaks` from 3 to the number of chunks you'd like.

```
library(dplyr)
tab %>%
  mutate(day_group = cut(Day, 3, include.lowest = TRUE, labels = FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(City, day_group) %>%
  summarise(mean_temp = mean(Temperature), start_day = min(Day), end_day = max(Day))

# Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
# Groups: City [?]
# 
#     City day_group mean_temp start_day end_day
#   (fctr)     (int)     (dbl)     (int)   (int)
# 1  Miami         1      26.0         1       2
# 2  Miami         2      28.5         3       4
# 3  Miami         3      30.5         5       6
# 4  Paris         1      16.0         1       2
# 5  Paris         2      13.5         3       4
# 6  Paris         3      10.5         5       6
```